# Json codes 1050 1100 and 1000

Tags: json

I'm trying to understand what kind of error codes I'm getting when I request a page that outputs a json application (I'm integrating a forecast script on my website from another website that provides this service)
When I request the json application at http://www.blabla.com/api/get?id=xxxxx&auth=(hash)
I get this error message:

```
{
"Message":"Bad request","Code":1050
}
```

What is this kind of error codes? I also got "Invalid input" and code: 1000 when I don't enter the authcode. Have anyone seen these message codes? What are the other code messages?
(I can't provide the website that provides the service because I risque being shut down)

Comment: That's not a [standard HTTP response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). You'd have to ask the web service provider.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) is only a "way of write data", it doesn't define error codes.

The errors you are getting are application-specific. In order to understand those code errors, you should look up into the documentation of "www.blabla.com"